# How to deploy Next.js app with nginx to subpath?

Tags: nginx, next.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

#### My goal

I would like to deploy my Next.js app with nginx to subpath.

#### My setting is the following:

1. Nginx config

```
location /subpath/ {
  proxy_redirect                      off;
  proxy_set_header Host               $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
  proxy_read_timeout          1m;
  proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3030/;
}
```

2. next.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
    basePath: '/subpath'
 }
```

#### Trouble

This next.config.js causes **mydomain.com/subpath/** to 404.

Otherwise, **mydomain.com/subpath/subpath** displayed the page. ><

(all other pages also needed **/subpath/subpath/xxx**)

(Every link href leads to 404, so I confirmed pages by typing **/subpath/subpath/** in address bar.)

#### Other info

The version of next.js is 10.0.4

#### How can I solve this?

I'm pleased to be provided with the knowledge of deploying next.js app to subpath.
Simplest way is better.

I will appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `next.config.js` don't needed `/subpath` it can be `root` path nginx will redirect to required path

Comment: Without basePath, front page html is rendered without css and js.
All next.js resources (such as `mydomain.com/_next/static/... ` ) don't include subpath and lead to 404

Comment: you can try [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration) to changing static folder route

Comment: did it solved your problem

Comment: I have same problem

Comment: Same issue here.. Were you ever able to resolve it?

Comment: I had a similar problem. I set `basePath` and `location` both without trailing slash and it started working.

Answer (score 3):

According to the configurations the problem here is with the trailing slash,

```
location /subpath/ {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:3030/;
}
```

change it to this,

```
location /subpath {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
}
```

and the complete config will be looks like this,

```
location /subpath {
  proxy_redirect                      off;
  proxy_set_header Host               $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
  proxy_read_timeout          1m;
  proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
}
```

The reason behind is **By default Next.js will redirect urls with trailing slashes to their counterpart without a trailing slash**. according to the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash)

But you've mentioned in the Nginx config that your url should have trailing slash. then it will return 404.

Comment: I have this config and I still get an error 404.

Answer (score 2):

## Summary

1. Modify `next.config.js`, add `basePath: '/subpath'`.
2. If you are using static files in `public` folder, please modify `src` where you have used, e.g.,

```js
     <Image
       src="/subpath/image.png"
       alt="Picture"
       width={500}
       height={500}
     />
```

3. Nginx location setting:

```
    location /subpath {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
```

4. Remember to disable your browser cache when you try it.

## Real sample

- nginx.conf (my next project run on 4000 port)
  [image: nginx.conf]
- next.config.js
  [image: next.config.js]
- static file src usage
  [image: static file src]